# Lua, Modify print function

Tags: lua

I am writing a generic Log() function in lua which utilizes lua print function:

```
Log (variable, 'String: %s ', str, 'Word: %d', w)
```

Currently I'm using below approach:

```
print(string.format (variable, 'String: %s ', str, 'Word: %d', w))
```

I tried something like:

```
Log = function(...) begin
return print(string.format(...))
end
```

But it doesn't work, Is this correct approach? Or Is there any better more generic way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to print a sequence of values, you can do that with `print`:

```
print(variable, 'String: %s ', str, 'Word: %d', w)
```

What you seem to want is something more complicated. Your algorithm seems to be:

1. For each argument:

   1. If the argument is not a string, then convert it to a string and print it.
   2. If the argument is a string, figure out how many `%` patterns it has (let us call this number *k*). Pass `string.format` the current argument string and the following *k* parameters, printing the resulting string. Advance *k* parameters.

That's a much more complicated algorithm than can be done in a one-line system.

Using Lua 5.3, here's what such a function would look like (note: barely tested code):

```
function Log(...)
    local values = {}

    local params = table.pack(...)

    local curr_ix = 1
    while (curr_ix <= params.n) do
        local value = params[curr_ix]
        if(type(value) == "string") then
            --Count the number of `%` characters, *except* for
            --sequential `%%`.
            local num_formats = 0
            for _ in value:gmatch("%%[^%%]") do
                num_formats = num_formats + 1
            end

            value = string.format(table.unpack(params, curr_ix, num_formats + curr_ix))

            curr_ix = curr_ix + num_formats
        end

        values[#values + 1] = value
        curr_ix = curr_ix + 1
    end

    print(table.unpack(values))
end
```

Comment: This is very interesting and YES it solves my problem to have a generic log function. Another addition I made by assigning flags for each log Classes. Log(Error,... ) Log(Info,... ) Log(Debug, ...) By having additional parameter, I could control verbosity. +1 for your help

Comment: This loop `for _ in value:gmatch("%%[^%%]") do` will match string `"5%% less"` despite of your intention to skip sequential percent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your current approach works, because the first argument of `string.format` expects the format specifier, not the rest of the arguments.

Anyway, this is the way to combine formatting and printing together:

```
Log = function(...)
  return print(string.format(...))
end
```

And call it like this:

```
Log("String: %s  Number: %d", 'hello' , 42)
```

---

Also, it might be better to make the format specifier argument more explicit, and use `io.write` instead of `print` to get more control over printing:

```
function Log(fmt, ...)
  return io.write(string.format(fmt, ...))
end
```

Comment: Specifying format will not be a generic solution, My example code is pretty basic but idea was to have completely generic Logger